# Need to add a column and set it as index to help speed up queries on a large table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, alter

I have this table below, it contains 26 million records. I am trying to add a id column that is an index as well. It will automatically increment existing records in the table to be 1, 2, 3 and so on. This will help speed up fetching records.

```
CREATE TABLE `rules` (
  `uuid` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alternate_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rule` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `advanced` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `notify_emails` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `rules_company_id_foreign` (`company_id`),
  KEY `rules_status_id_foreign` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rules_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rules_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `rule_statuses` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here is my alter sql:

```
ALTER TABLE rules ADD id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD INDEX (id)
```

During my testing in my local environment, I have 3.6 million records, it takes 117 seconds. I am worried running this on production where it has 26 million records, it will timeout or crash the database.

Is there anyway I could improve my alter sql to speed it up?

Comment: run it from the shell so it will not timeout, but the question why you have already an uuid what do you need it for`

Comment: We don't expose table.id in api responses, but we do show table.uuid, security reasons

Comment: How does adding an auto-increment help speed up fetching records if you're using `uuid` as the lookup key? Also uuid as utf8 is wasteful in length (only latin is used), (and since 10.7, uuid is its [own uuid datatype](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/), that [behave the same way](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-uuid-data-type/) and are stored in an index optimized way for uuidv4 types).

Comment: If you use an uuid, it might be not necessary to have an extra id as primary key. However your uuid is not optimal, they way you store them, the format and the order. Take a look at https://lefred.be/content/mysql-uuids/ . Now if you really want to modify your table without locking for too long check for something like pt-online-schema-change